# jquery: select clicked td table element with multiple different id's and other tds on same page

Tags: php, jquery, selector

I am building scheduling software.  I am using a number of tables to display times/dates, etc.

In one particular table there are cells with id's that list the date and employee id number.

I am trying to setup a trading shift system.  When the cell is click an ajax function is performed.

Here is an example cell:

```
<td id="tblcell-2013_03_13-id_3" class="displayShift">$data placed here</td>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // I can't do this because each id is different
  $("td#tblcell").click(function () {
    alert('it works!');

  });

  // I can't do this because there other other td elements on the same page in other tables
  $("td").click(function () {
    alert('it works!');
  });

});
```

How do I set up a function that is activated when a specific cell is clicked that also  passess var data to the function in a script that has other td table elements that can't be referenced in this function?

thanks

Comment: Please post more of your HTML and an example of what else should be accessed from other cells when a cell is clicked. Most obviously would be to use the class selector. `$('.displayShift').click(function() {console.log($(this));});`  where `$(this)` is the clicked cell.

Comment: I din't get it, sorry. Which are those `other td table elements` and everything can be referenced from everywhere unless it's scoped but DOM elements aren't that case so they're referable.

Comment: kidwon, thanks for reply.  there are other table td elements and other tables with their own td's.. so using a generic "td" selector as a click func will trigger all of these other td elements.  I have set up a demo of the problme here:  http://jsfiddle.net/NMGNb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `td[id^="tblcell"]` selector to select all TDs with their ID starting with `tblcell`

```
$('td[id^="tblcell"]').click(function() {
    // ... do stuff ...
});
```

**Demo for attribute-value-starts-with selector**: http://jsfiddle.net/ARkxD/

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  I didnt know you could do that so I learned something.  I tried it and Firebug gives no errors.  When I click a cell the alert doesn't fire.  Nothing happens.  No errors. I am using jquery 1.8.2 and jqueryiu 1.9.1

Comment: thanks for the demo.  try clicking on my demo.. it's ugly.. try clicking on a td with initials "DD" "FH" etc.. it doesnt fire:  http://jsfiddle.net/NMGNb/

Comment: You hadn't included jQuery in your demo (on the left panel in jsfiddle). I've updated it with jquery included (no other change). It works now. http://jsfiddle.net/NMGNb/1/

Comment: thanks you! it works.  amazing and I learned something very valuable today.  thanks